# How to build git with dynamic linkage to dependencies

Tags: git, makefile, dynamic-linking, autoconf

I use the following to build git

```bash
local gitVersion="2.37.0"
url="https://github.com/git/git/archive/refs/tags/v$gitVersion.tar.gz"

tempDir=$(mktemp -d) &&
        mkdir -p "$tempDir" &&
        (
            cd "$tempDir" &&
                curl -L "$url" -o git.tar.gz &&
                tar -xf git.tar.gz &&
                cd "$tempDir/git-"* &&
                make configure &&
                ./configure --prefix="/usr/local" \
                    --with-curl \
                    --with-expat \
                    --with-openssl \
                    --without-python \
                    --without-tcltk \
                    --sysconfdir=/etc \
                    --with-gitconfig=/etc/gitconfig &&
                make -j all\
        )
```

This results in heavy executables in `/usr/local/libexec/git-core` where each executable has a size of 21mb,

```bash
ldd /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-checkout
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe24991000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb635ef0000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb635ce8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb635ac8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb635703000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb636108000)
```

due to linking statically. The distributions `git` links dynamically

```bash
ldd /usr/libexec/git-core/git-checkout
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff5755c000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007ff1a7744000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff1a752c000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff1a730c000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff1a7104000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ff1a6c1b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff1a6856000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff1a7f56000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff1a6652000)
```

How can I achieve the same result? Is there any option in configure?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the /libexec/git-core folder contains no hardlinks, its the full executable... in the distribution its a hardlink to git exe... Whats the problem here.

Comment: The Git makefile has about a bazillion options. The most interesting two here are `NO_INSTALL_HARDLINKS` (disables hard-linking of the all-in-one executable) and `INSTALL_SYMLINKS` (makes the core built-ins symbolic links to the all-in-one). There's also `INSTALL_STRIP` for removing symbol table information; this defaults to disabled.